# Can .NET 5 Runtime run .NET 3.1 application?

Tags: compatibility, .net-5, .net-core-3.1

I have an exe built using .NET Core 3.1. If the installer is run on a system that has .NET 5 runtime installed, it is still prompting the user to install .NET Core 3.1.
How to make this exe run on a system just having .NET 5 runtime installed?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run a .NET 3.1 app on the .NET 5 runtime. A 3.1 app requires that you install the runtime for .NET 3.1 as well. Major version changes indicate a new runtime (e.g. .NET Core 2 requires the .NET Core 2.x runtime, .NET Core 3 requires the .NET Core 3.x runtime).

Note that you can write code for an app that runs on both .NET 3.1 and .NET 5 but they are compiled separately, produce separate binaries and dependencies and the appropriate version would need to be deployed onto the target machine based upon the runtime that is installed.

[.NET and .NET Core official support policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core)